# Azure CosmosDB: how to ORDER BY id?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Using a vanilla CosmosDB collection (all default), adding documents like this:

```
{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Hannah"
}
```

I would like to retrieve records ordered by id, like this:

```
SELECT c.id FROM c
ORDER BY c.id
```

This give me the error `Order-by item requires a range index to be defined on the corresponding index path.`

I expect this is because /id is hash indexed and not range indexed. I've tried to change the Indexing Policy in various ways, but any change I make which would touch / or /id gets wiped when I save.

How can I retrieve documents ordered by ID?

Comment: Have you tried adding a range index to `id` in addition to the existing hash index?

Comment: I put in the policy shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47015229/azure-cosmosdb-order-by-item-requires-a-range-index - now my query yield the error "Primary key order-by is not supported".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this is to store a duplicate property e.g. `id2` that has the same value of `id`, and is indexed using a range index, then use that for sorting, i.e. query for `SELECT * FROM c ORDER BY c.id2`.

PS: The reason this is not supported is because id is part of a composite index (which is on partition key and row key; `id` is the row key part) The Cosmos DB team is working on a change that will allow sorting by id.

**EDIT**: new collections now support ORDER BY c.id as of 7/12/19

Comment: "a change that will _not_ allow" ? can you update with the present state of this facility please?

Comment: I have CosmosDB instances in prod and dev environments. On dev env ordery id works well, but on prod I faced "Primary key order-by is not supported." - a horrible situation to be in!

Answer (score 0):

I found this page [CosmosDB Indexing Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies) , which has the below Note that may be helpful:

> Azure Cosmos DB returns an error when a query uses ORDER BY but
>   doesn't have a Range index against the queried path ***with the maximum
>   precision***.

Some other information from elsewhere in the document:

> Range supports efficient equality queries, range queries (using >, <,
>   >=, <=, !=), and ORDER BY queries. ORDER By queries by default also require maximum index precision (-1). The data type can be String or
>   Number.

Some guidance on types of queries assisted by Range queries:

> Range Range over /prop/? (or /) can be used to serve the following
>   queries efficiently:
>
> SELECT FROM collection c WHERE c.prop = "value"
>
> SELECT FROM collection c WHERE c.prop > 5
>
> SELECT FROM collection c ORDER BY c.prop

And a code example from the docs also:

```
var rangeDefault = new DocumentCollection { Id = "rangeCollection" };

// Override the default policy for strings to Range indexing and "max" (-1) precision
rangeDefault.IndexingPolicy = new IndexingPolicy(new RangeIndex(DataType.String) { Precision = -1 });

await client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri("db"), rangeDefault);
```

Hope this helps,

J